# Transfer Google Spreadsheets to another User and ensure scripts work as new user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have some complicated Google Sheets that have multiple scripts and each time the current owner moves on and has to transfer the sheet to another user all the scripts break as they were not transferred with the Sheet.

Am looking to see what others have done to remedy this?  Is there a different way to manage the scripts so that this is not an issue?

One possibility we thought of was create an account that would own these sheets, but that can get costly if we do that for each group.

Comment: You could try creating a library of scripts, and manage sharing that way.